# resolved lint issues still showing on build server

Tags: android, lint

I resolved the lint issues on my local machine. but when push it build server, it is still showing me the same errors.
Ex. if solved the lint type- unused resources in string.xml by deleting that resource and push it to the server , it is showing me that error again but if i go to that line of error in file, it is not there, but line is still highlighted.

Comment: Refresh the project cache on your server

Comment: And where to find that in project folder structure?

Comment: What is not clear in **on your server**?